# exception: wrong final block length...aes decryption

Tags: java, android, encryption

what I'm trying to achieve is an AES CBC decryption  [like this in android](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3965/zb4tj2or_jpg.htm%5D%5BIMG%5Dhttp://fs2.directupload.net/images/150422/temp/zb4tj2or.jpg)
using [online tool](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/)

I'm not really an android developer, and the following code doesn't have to be 100% secure(just for an example)
encrypting works just fine, but I'm really stuck with the decrypting:

the line with:  `AESCrypt.decrypt(key2, ivBytes, todecode);`
throws the exception
I think the problem is something about the actual dataconversion of the "key2" and "todecode" variables... anyone know what I am missing?

settings:

```
private static final String TAG = "AESCrypt";

// AESCrypt-ObjC uses CBC and PKCS7Padding
private static final String AES_MODE = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";

// AESCrypt-ObjC uses SHA-256 (and so a 256-bit key)
private static final String HASH_ALGORITHM = "SHA-256";





    byte[] key = hexStringToByteArray("E0E1E2E3E5E6E7E8EAEBECEDEFF0F1F2");
    SecretKeySpec key2 = new SecretKeySpec(key, 0, key.length, "AES");
    byte[] ivBytes = hexStringToByteArray("12CEC438810CFA399A81139AF7D648BC");
    byte[] todecode = Base64.decode("CD46009A232420B2CBF6E4148EE17AA4",
            Base64.NO_WRAP);
    try {

        resultbytes = AESCrypt.decrypt(key2, ivBytes, todecode);
        result = resultbytes.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        feedbackBody.append("catch blok \n");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    feedbackBody.append(result + " \n");



public static byte[] decrypt(final SecretKeySpec key, final byte[] iv,
        final byte[] decodedCipherText) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decodedCipherText);

    log("decryptedBytes", decryptedBytes);

    return decryptedBytes;
}
```

edit: seems like the input data is the fault here:

if i encrypt raw data and decrypt it right after that, it works just fine...
but I get the decrypted file from elsewhere

suspect the error around the encoding from the string:     `Base64.decode("CD46009A232420B2CBF6E4148EE17AA4", Base64.NO_WRAP);`

Comment: does your AES_MODE include padding? I would think that this error indicates that the encrypted message was too short, are you sure the encrypted message was correctly saved as Base64. If you included the stack trace it would be obvious. The keys coused error will have stack trace includign cipher.init, while the wrong message will start at cipher.doFinal

Comment: Your own answer doesn't make any sense when looking at the question. Please edit your question to include a full encryption/decryption cycle.

Answer (score 7):

Please try using the following methods for AES encryption and decryption, they are tested over long time:

```
 public static String encrytData(String text) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
    byte[] static_key = Constants.AES_KEY.getBytes();

    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(static_key, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.IV_VECTOR);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

    byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());

    String result = Base64.encodeToString(results, Base64.NO_WRAP|Base64.DEFAULT);
    return result;

}


public static String decryptData(String text)throws Exception{

    byte[] encryted_bytes = Base64.decode(text, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
    byte[] static_key = Constants.AES_KEY.getBytes();

    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(static_key, "AES");
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(Constants.IV_VECTOR);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryted_bytes);
    String result = new String(decrypted);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: **1.** Always use `getBytes()` and `new String()` with the same additional charset string, because different systems may use different defaults. **2.** Generate a new random IV and prepend it to the ciphertext, otherwise it's not semantically secure. **3.** Add ciphertext authentication. This can be done as an encrypt-then-MAC scheme (i.e. HMAC-SHA256) or use an authenticated mode like GCM (java support), CCM, EAX.

Answer (score 2):

ZeroBytePadding at the AES_MODE did the magic!!

```
private static final String AES_MODE = "AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding";
```

also: 
Base64.decode(...) on line 4 made some problems, changed to hexStringToByteArray(...) and it now works just fine :D